# Динамическое создание ActiveForm в yii2

Tags: yii2

вот и я дошел до того момента, чтобы задать здесь вопрос.
Просьба шапками не закидывать, я еще молод и зелен

Пытаюсь в вид с помощью AJAX отрисовать модальное окно с формой ActiveForm,обращаюсь к контроллеру, который на основе полученных данных с помощью хелпера должен конструировать это модальное окно.

JS - вызывается по onclick на кнопке

```
function createComplaint(objectType, objectId, subjectId) {
    let data = {
        _csrf: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr("content"),
        ajax: {
            objectType: objectType,
            objectId: objectId,
            subjectId: subjectId,
        },
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/u-i/create-complaint-window',
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#complaintZone').html(response);
        }
    })
}
```

Экшн в контроллере

```
public function actionCreateComplaintWindow(): Response
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->getRequest();

        if (!$request->isAjax) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        //Переменные фактически не используются сейчас, но они будут нужны
        $objectType = $request->post('ajax')['objectType'];
        $objectId = $request->post('ajax')['objectId'];
        $subjectId = $request->post('ajax')['subjectId'];

        return $this->asJson(ConstructHtml::test($objectType, $objectId, $subjectId));
    }
```

Хелпер - один из вариантов, как я пробовал, в данном случае yii комментирует строки с тегами php

```
public static function test(string $objectType, int $objectId, int $subjectId): string
    {
        $html = "<style>body {overflow: hidden;}</style>" .
            "<div style='position: fixed;left: 0;top: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;background: #000;opacity: .6;z-index: 10000'></div>" .
            "<div class='modal fade show' id='complaintWindow' tabindex='-1' aria-modal='true' style='display: block;z-index: 10001'>" .
            "<div class='modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered'>" .
            "<div class='modal-content rounded-0' style='border-color: black'>" .
            "<div class='modal-header'>" .
            "<h1 class='modal-title fs-5'>Отправить жалобу</h1>" .
            "<button type='button' onclick='closeComplaintWindow()' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='modal' aria - label = 'Close' ></button>" .
            "</div> " .
            "<div class='modal-body'> ";
        $options = '[
            "options" => ["class" => "form-floating"],
            "errorOptions" => ["class" => "text-danger small", "id" => "errorLabel"],
            "template" => "{input}\n{label}\n{error}",
        ]';
        $html .= '<?php $activeForm = ActiveForm::begin(["id" => "complaint-form",
            "options" => [
                "style" => "width: 100%;padding-left: 5%;padding-right: 5%;",
            ],
            "enableAjaxValidation" => true,
            "validateOnType" => true,
            "action" => Url::to("/u-i/send-complaint"),
            "validationUrl" => Url::to("/u-i/send-complaint"),
        ]) ?>';
        $html .= '<?= $activeForm->field($complaintForm, "complaint", ' . $options . ')->textarea([
                "placeholder" => "complaint",
                "id" => "commentArea",
                "style" => "min-height: 150px",
            ])
            ->label("Жалоба", ["class" => false]) ?>';
        $html .= '<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>';
        $html .=
            "</div> " .
            "<div class='modal-footer'> " .
            "<button type='button' onclick='closeComplaintWindow()' class='btn btn-secondary' data - bs - dismiss = 'modal'> " .
            "Отмена" .
            " </button> " .
            "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'> Отправить</button> " .
            "</div>" .
            "</div>" .
            "</div>" .
            "</div>";

        return $html;
    }
```

[image: Пример вывода с кодом как в хелпере]

Можно ли вообще реализовать то, что я пытаюсь или это все ерунда какая то?

Comment: "Можно ли вообще реализовать то, что я пытаюсь или это все ерунда какая то?"  ---- а что конкретно? модальное окно- можно.... Только тут не сформулирована проблема. Данные отправляются и получаются.....что именно не так - не ясно

Comment: В целом мне нужно модальное окно, с input полем внутри, которое отрисовывается с помощью ActiveForm.    Если я пытаюсь передать все в виде строки (как на примере хелпера из вопроса), то Yii2 комментирует строки с тегами php, если я пытаюсь ActiveForm создать прямо в хелпере , то я не могу вернуть данные в вид (через ajax функцию), потому что "заголовки уже переданы"

Comment: А на картинке показывается нормально всё. .........а в целом надо отсылать не json а `$this->renderAjax(тут путь к шаблону)`  тогда вернётся html с оправкой на то, что это ajax запрос

Comment: Кстати, почему форма сделана таким извращённым способом ,а не банально сделана через `view` шаблон?

Comment: Я ранее не знал, что можно рендерить еще один вид (с формой) если вид уже рендерился и пытался через метод в отдельном классе нарисовать то, что нужно передать в уже существующий вид, я еще молод)

Comment: $this->renderAjax Это именно то, что было нужно, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблемы в контроллере, надо было рендерить отдельный вид с нужным мне контентом через $this->renderAjax($вид, [$параметры])